# Rails 6: Unpermitted Parameter : Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I have a model called `Answer` that can have many attachments. I have specified it as `has_many_attached :answer_files` and permitted the parameter as per the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/active_storage_overview.html#has-many-attached) however in this model I keep getting `Unpermitted parameter: :#<ActiveStorage::Attached::Many:0x0000000012e76aa0>` in the logs. I have the same in another model using `has_one_attached :logo` and that works fine.

Do note that I am using `direct_upload: true` as per the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads) in both models. What I do not understand is that the record does save and the files are being added to the active_storage_blobs table. It is just not being associated with my model.

I have also tried to re-install active storage to no avail.

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this with the assistance of u/endenis on Reddit. The answer is part of an association and I thought that I have to do it like this `f.file_field answer.answer_files, multiple: true, direct_upload: true` but that is incorrect.

I had to do it this way `f.file_field :answer_files, multiple: true, direct_upload: true`